# Possible to perform a NOT IN for one-to-many relationship with Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, collections, criteria

I have a question about Hibernate and if it's possible to achieve the query using the Criteria API with the current data model structure I'm using. I have a data model with the following structure:

ParentClass contains a List:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity =       org.test.ChildClass.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "child_uuid")
private List<ChildClass> childList = new ArrayList<ChildClass>();
```

The child class has one field:

```
private String testField
```

The query I'm attempting to write can be expressed as follows:

Return a list of all ParentClass objects that have the ABSENCE OF an object ChildClass that has a "testField" value of "1". In other words, there must not be an object in that list that has the testField value of 1.

Currently I have this query:

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(org.test.ParentClass);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

    criteria.createAlias("childList", "c");
    SimpleExpression expression = Restrictions.ne("c.testField", "1");
    criteria.add(expression);

    return (List<T>) criteria.list();
```

What happens is that I will get any ParentClass objects that contain at least one ChildClass that has a value of c.testField other than "1". This includes ParentClass objects that DO have a "testField" value of "1", which I'm trying to exclude entirely.

The table structure has ChildClass having a reference to ParentClass, but not vice versa. So it seems that each ChildClass object is joined with the ParentClass, and if they fulfill the above restriction, that ParentClass gets returned. This is the incorrect result as it means a ParentClass that has two ChildClass objects, one with value "1" and the other with value "2" will get returned.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the equivalent of the following HQL query:

```
select distinct p from Parent p
where not exists (select c.id from Parent p2 join p2.children c 
                  where c.testField = '1' and p2.id = p.id)
```

You should be able to translate that to Criteria (if you really want to use criteria instead of using clearer HQL queries). You'll need to use [`Subqueries.notExists()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html#notExists%28org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria%29).

Comment: Thanks JB, this is pushing me in the right direction. I've got this now, and what happens is it returns ALL ParentClasses if no child has testField = '1', and NONE if any do. Do you know how I would go about applying this on an individual level to each ParentClass?

Comment: Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(org.test.ParentClass);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forEntityName("org.test.ChildClass", "c");
        dc.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("c.uuid")));
        dc.add(Restrictions.eq("c.testField", "1"));
        criteria.add(Subqueries.notExists(dc));

Comment: You forgot to translate the restriction `p2.id = p.id`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(org.test.ParentClass,"parent");
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

criteria.createAlias("parent.ChildClass", "pc");
SimpleExpression expression = Restrictions.ne("pc.testField", "1");
criteria.add(expression);

return (List<T>) criteria.list();
```

Comment: That will retrieve all the parents having at least one child having testField != 1.